# canvas javascript problem

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am asked to develop an application that will run on Blackberry. But I don't knowledge in java. Since the application needs drawing, I opt for html5 and javascript. Then I read some javascript tutorials. But when I try to put it into practice it, I get error saying that the "getContext" attribut is undefined.
Is it possible to write it in c#?

```
var canvasCircle;
var contextCircle;
var x = 400;
var y = 300;
var dx = 2;
var WIDTH = 800;
var HEIGHT = 600;

// the circle wont make any transsformation.
function draw_circle(x, y, r) {
    contextCircle.beginPath();
    contextCircle.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    contextCircle.closePath();
    contextCircle.stroke();
}

function clear_canvas() {
    contextCircle.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
    canvasCircle = document.getElementById("canvas_circle");
    contextCircle = canvasCircle.getContext('2d');
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() {
    clear_canvas();
    draw_circle(x, y, 50);

    if (x + dx > WIDTH || x + dx < 0)
        dx = -dx;
    x += dx;
}
init();

<canvas id="canvas_circle" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: **Huh?** What does C# have to do with anything?

Comment: No, you cannot write JavaScript in C#.

Comment: @EMMERICH: Wrong.  http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

Comment: Are you sure the browser support canvas?

Comment: @EMMERICH: http://jsc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Apparently we have different interpretations of what writing JavaScript is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Blackberry browser you are using, but it looks like it doesn't support Canvas. Dive Into HTML5 has a great chapter on feature detection: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html

It also has a nice library called Modernizr you can use to detect HTML5 features. But to check for canvas support is pretty simple (as the chapter shows):

```
 function supports_canvas() {
     return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is not the browser. But maybe the way I am using or declaring functions and global variables in JavaScript. I have a code that runs find with canvas. My problem is that, I have tree functions